# System error when opening macro &H800700C1

Tags: excel, vba

I was using regularly a macro add-in in excel which stopped working all of a sudden.

I get several error messages in the following order when I launch the macro:

1/ System error &H800700C1 (-2147024703)

2/ When I click on OK, "Insufficient memory" warning appears and the VBA editor opens with the first warning of system error &H800700C1 (-2147024703)

3/ When I click on OK again, I get the message "Cannot run the macro "RubanCHarge". The Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled".

However, I have alread enabled all macros in the Trust Center, as well as I checked "Trust access to the VBA project object model"

Can anybody help?
Many thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50970449/11683?

Comment: So "all of a sudden" just after some updates possibly?

Comment: I haven't noticed any updates

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is an office update
To fix it you have to revert the last update (Version 2204 Build 16.0.15128.20178) :

1. Download Office deployment tool, unzip the files into a folder "RevertOffice"
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117
2. Check your version
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date
3. Change the .xml to download the good version
   in MY case, office 365 64bits, the XML is :

> ```
> <Configuration>
>   <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Current" Version="16.0.15028.20160">
>     <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
>       <Language ID="en-us" />
>     </Product>
>   </Add>
> </Configuration>
> ```

4. Open a powershell, go to the directory "Revert Office" hosting the setup.exe and your xlm file

   .\setup.exe /download configuration-Office365-x64.xml

Wait for the download, it will create you a "Office" folder

5. When the download is done :

   .\setup.exe /configure configuration-Office365-x64.xml

Office set up will start, install it,
In my case I didn't have to reboot the version changed directly

Don't forget to go to Office account and disable the updates

Max